# Powershell method with Action<T> parameter

Tags: c#, powershell

How to execute a method that has `Action<T>` as a parameter in Powershell?

```cs
upgradeEngine.Configure(c => c.ScriptExecutor.ExecutionTimeoutSeconds = 15 * 60);
```

C# code:

```cs
var upgradeEngine = DeployChanges.To
    .SqlDatabase(connectionString)
    .WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .LogToConsole();

//this line
upgradeEngine.Configure(c => c.ScriptExecutor.ExecutionTimeoutSeconds = 15 * 60);

//this line
upgradeEngine.Build();
```

```bsh
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path -Path $currentPath -ChildPath 'x:\location\of\DbUp.dll')

$dbUp = [DbUp.DeployChanges]::To
$dbUp = [SqlServerExtensions]::SqlDatabase($dbUp, $connectionString)
$dbUp = [StandardExtensions]::WithScriptsFromFileSystem($dbUp, $scriptPath)
$dbUp = [StandardExtensions]::LogToConsole($dbUp)
$upgradeResult = $dbUp.Build().PerformUpgrade()
```

Comment: GSerg, there is no usage of argument from this method

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but the delegate accepts a parameter `$i` and uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct a ScriptBlock with the appropriate signature and cast it as `[Action[T]]`

```
$delegate = [System.Action[DbUp.Builder.UpgradeConfiguration]]{
  param([DbUp.Builder.UpgradeConfiguration]$c)
  $c.ScriptExecutor.ExecutionTimeoutSeconds = 15 * 60
}
$DbUp.Configure($delegate)
```